# Cannot convert value of type 'NSControl.StateValue' to expected argument type 'Int'

Tags: swift, macos

I'm not sure why I can't get this to work. I'm following a video tutorial and this doesn't happen in the video, any help or advice in learning Mac OS development would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks - Image attached in link

Line 31: Cannot convert value of type 'NSControl.StateValue' to expected argument type 'Int'

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value: file To_do_list/ViewController.swift, line 31

Line 31 = if importantCheckbox.state == 0 {

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  To do list
//
//  Created by on 18/11/2021.
//

import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var importantCheckbox: NSButton!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
    
override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()

// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
       
}

@IBAction func addClicked(_ sender: NSButton) {
if textField.stringValue != "" {
            
if let context = (NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.persistentContainer.viewContext {
                
let toDoItem = ToDoItem(context: context)
                
toDoItem.name = textField.stringValue
if importantCheckbox.state == 0 {
//Not Important
toDoItem.important = false
} else {
//Important
toDoItem.important = true
}
                
// (NSApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.saveAction(nil)
}
          
}
}
    
}
[Cannot convert value of type 'NSControl.StateValue' to expected argument type 'Int'][1]
```

Answer (score 1):

[NSControl.StateValue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nscontrol/statevalue) is a kind of enum. The *cases* are `.on`, `.off` and `.mixed`.

You have to check for one of the cases for example

```
if importantCheckbox.state == .off {
```

or check for the `rawValue`

```
if importantCheckbox.state.rawValue == 0 {
```

Comment: Definitely don't check the raw value. It's not guaranteed to be stable